# Get type of a "singleton type"

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

We can create a literal types via shapeless:

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
var x = 42.narrow
// x: Int(42) = 42
```

But how can I operate with `Int(42)` as a type if it's even impossible to create type alias

```
type Answ = Int(42) // won't compile
// or
def doSmth(value: Int(42)) = ... // won't compile
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In [Typelevel Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/scala) you can write just

   ```
   val x: 42 = 42

   type Answ = 42

   def doSmth(value: 42) = ???
   ```
2. In [Dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/) Scala you can write the same.
3. In [Lightbend Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (i.e. standard Scala) + Shapeless you can write

   ```
   import shapeless.Witness
   import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

   val x: Witness.`42`.T = 42.narrow

   type Answ = Witness.`42`.T

   def doSmth(value: Witness.`42`.T) = ???
   ```

In case 1) build.sbt should be

```
scalaOrganization := "org.typelevel"
scalaVersion := "2.12.3-bin-typelevel-4"
scalacOptions += "-Yliteral-types"
```

In case 2) build.sbt should be

```
scalaOrganization := "ch.epfl.lamp"
scalaVersion := "0.3.0-RC2"
```

and plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.lamp" % "sbt-dotty" % "0.1.5")
```

In case 3) build.sbt should be

```
scalaOrganization := "org.scala-lang"
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.2"
```

4. or you can use Typelevel Scala and Shapeless at the same time.

---

**Update.** Since version 2.13.0 there are literal types in standard Scala

```
val x: 42 = 42
val x1: 42 = valueOf[42]

type Answ = 42

def doSmth(value: 42) = ???
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/v2.13.0 (Language changes / Literal types)

Answer (score 2):

`Int(42)` is not a valid Scala syntax for type.

IIRC singleton types were implemented in scalac for a while, but programmers had no syntax of defining such. Shapeless provides that, with macros, as well as some extra machinery.

In particular, `shapeless.Witness` is an object that contains both type information and associated value, and also can be summoned from either.

```
import shapeless.Witness
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
import shapeless.test.illTyped // test string for causing type-errors when compiled

// --- Type aliases ---
val w = 42.witness
type Answ1 = w.T // that is your Int(42) singleton type
type Answ2 = Witness.`42`.T // same, but without extra variable
implicitly[Answ1 =:= Answ2] // compiles, types are the same

// --- Value definitions ---
val a: Answ1 = 42 // compiles, value OK, and no need to `narrow`
illTyped { "val b: Answ1 = 43" } // would not compile
val c: Witness.`43`.T = 43 // that syntax is OK here too

// --- Summoning values ---
val answ = Witness[Answ1].value // will not compile for non-singleton
def genericSingletonMethod[A](implicit W: Witness.Aux[A]) = s"Summoning ${W.value}"
assert { genericSingletonMethod[Answ1] == "Summoning 42" }
assert { genericSingletonMethod[Witness.`"string"`.T] == "Summoning string" }
```