# Scala cross compiling literal types

Tags: scala, shapeless, singleton-type, scala-2.12, scala-2.13

Is there a way to cross compile literal types to Scala 2.12?

Let's say

```scala
def foo[S <: String](implicit V: ValueOf[S]): String = V.value

println(foo["bar"])
```

Shapeless can encode literal types with `shapeless.Witness`, so it should be possible to shim `ValueOf`, or provide another type class with Scala version specific implementations. But I'm a bit lost about what do to do with the expression `foo["bar"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo["bar"]` isn't parsable in 2.12.

You should use `` foo[Witness.`"bar"`.T] ``

```
def foo[S <: String](implicit V: Witness.Aux[S]): String = V.value

println(foo[Witness.`"bar"`.T]) //bar
```

[Get type of a "singleton type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181854/get-type-of-a-singleton-type/)

Comment: Hoped there was a more elegant way than using Witness for this, oh well

Comment: @gogstad well, there is also slightly outdated Typelevel fork of Scala https://github.com/typelevel/scala and compiler plugin https://github.com/jeremyrsmith/literal-types

Comment: @gogstad If the issue is word `Witness` being too long you can introduce alias like it's done in https://github.com/fthomas/refined ``W.`"bar"`.T``.